# Header is Scroll in Android how to fix it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

In my project header is fix in top of the screen.

when i click on edit text the virtual keyboard is open that time header is scroll up and not visible in screen.

how to fix it in my screen.

please give me suggestion.

Thank You.

My code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_one"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.Header
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_one"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="100"
                    android:text="New Lead Entry"
                    android:textColor="#3a4e6c"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_time"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="City:" />

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_city"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="City"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:maxLength="35"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_state"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="State:" />

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/et_state"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:dropDownHeight="200dp"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="State"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:maxLength="2"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_zip"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Zip:" />

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_zip"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="11742"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="7"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_optional"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularGray"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Optional Items"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Phone 1:" />

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_phone_one"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="(999) 555-1212"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:maxLength="15"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_phone_two"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Phone 2:" />

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_phone_two"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="(999) 555-1212"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:maxLength="15"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_email"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Email:" />

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_email"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Email"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:maxLength="100"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_date"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_product"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Product Interest:" />

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/ll_product_list"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:padding="10dp" >
                    </AutoCompleteTextView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_alt_one"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Alt 1:" />

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_alt_one"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_alt_two"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Alt 2:" />

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_alt_two"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_date"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDateLabel"
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Date:" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtDateLabel"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                            android:id="@+id/et_date"
                            style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_date"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:hint="Date"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_time"
                            android:paddingRight="1dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:tag="200" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_date"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/close"
                            android:padding="15dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_time"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txttimeLabel"
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Time:" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txttimeLabel"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                            android:id="@+id/et_time"
                            style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_time"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:hint="Time"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_time"
                            android:paddingRight="1dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:tag="200" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_time"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/close"
                            android:padding="15dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:weightSum="10" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Comments / Notes:" />

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_comments"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                        android:gravity="top|left"
                        android:lines="4"
                        android:maxLength="2000"
                        android:tag="200" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_waiver"
                        style="@style/TextRegularWhite_other"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="DNC Waiver:" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/tbtn_dnc_waiver"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_waiver"
                        android:background="@drawable/toggle_button"
                        android:textOff=""
                        android:textOn="" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_attachment"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_btn_orange"
                        android:tag="200"
                        android:text="Submit"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**in Manifest not set any windowSoftInputMode.**

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep your header part out of scroll view ..

Firstly use Relative OR Linear layout as your first container .. then after keep your Header layout .. and then user scroll view for rest of your layout ..

That's it .. you are good to go  ..

For Ex:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
// Then your header view starts ..

// Then your header view ends ..



// Your scroll view starts ..
   // your child layout starts

   // your child layout ends

// Your scroll view ends ..

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do it like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_one"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.Header
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_one"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:tag="100"
                android:text="New Lead Entry"
                android:textColor="#3a4e6c"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_time"
                style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:tag="200" />
        </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="City:" />

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_city"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="City"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:maxLength="35"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_state"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="State:" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/et_state"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:dropDownHeight="200dp"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="State"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_zip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Zip:" />

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_zip"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="11742"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="7"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_optional"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                style="@style/TextRegularGray"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:tag="200"
                android:text="Optional Items"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Phone 1:" />

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_phone_one"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="(999) 555-1212"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="15"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_phone_two"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Phone 2:" />

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_phone_two"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="(999) 555-1212"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="15"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_email"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Email:" />

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_email"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_date"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_product"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Product Interest:" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/ll_product_list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:padding="10dp" >
                </AutoCompleteTextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_alt_one"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Alt 1:" />

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_alt_one"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_alt_two"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Alt 2:" />

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_alt_two"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_date"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDateLabel"
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Date:" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtDateLabel"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        android:id="@+id/et_date"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_date"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Date"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_time"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/close"
                        android:padding="15dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_time"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txttimeLabel"
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Time:" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txttimeLabel"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                        android:id="@+id/et_time"
                        style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_time"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Time"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_time"
                        android:paddingRight="1dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:tag="200" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_time"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/close"
                        android:padding="15dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Comments / Notes:" />

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_comments"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/rowbg"
                    android:gravity="top|left"
                    android:lines="4"
                    android:maxLength="2000"
                    android:tag="200" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <com.esp.leadtransit.uc.EspTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_waiver"
                    style="@style/TextRegularWhite_other"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="DNC Waiver:" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/tbtn_dnc_waiver"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_waiver"
                    android:background="@drawable/toggle_button"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn="" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_attachment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
                    style="@style/TextRegularBlack"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_btn_orange"
                    android:tag="200"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: when keyboard is open then header is scroll still it's not working